# Python использование next()

Tags: python, next

```
def generator(x):
    x = x ** (1 / 3)

    return x

gen = generator(19683)
for i in range(10):
    print(next(gen))
```

Данная функция будет находить кубический корень следующего числа.
Вход: 19683
Вывод: 27, 3 ... 10 раз

Я понимаю что нужно что-то добавить в саму функцию, что бы та принимала уже следующее значение а не статическое которое было в начале. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать

Answer (score 1):

Переделайте функцию в генератор:

```
def generator(x):
    while True:
        x = x ** (1 / 3)
        yield x


gen = generator(19683)
for i in range(10):
    print(next(gen))
```

Comment: и всё же, корень третьего степени 27 это не 3, а 2.99999996. Как исправить именно это без range

Comment: Я перезадал ваш вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1387514/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b1-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5