# Как извлечь кубический корень как можно точнее?

Tags: python

Популярный способ извлечь кубический корень из вещественного числа такой: `x ** (1 / 3)`. Но он не самый точный: `19683 ** (1 / 3)` -> `26.999999999999996`, хотя для обратной функции `27 ** 3 == 19683`. Налицо неточность. И да, я знаю что вещественные числа считают приближенно...

Как извлечь корень кубический максимально точно?

Comment: Кажется, для этого придётся искать какие-то специальные математические библиотеки. Число 1/3 невозможно представить в виде конечной десятичной дроби (поэтому использовать decimal не годится), а результат извлечения корня в общем случае не обязательно окажется рациональным числом

Comment: @andreymal , двоичный поиск для кубической функции должен выдать самый точный представимый результат. Не так ли?

Answer (score 3):

Ну вот такая есть библиотека, например:

```
import gmpy2

print(gmpy2.root(19683, 3))
```

Вывод:

```
27.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Может стоит попробовать `numpy`? Эта библиотека, вроде, куда точнее проводит вычисления. [Информацию взял отсюда](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/kak-izvlech-kubicheskij-koren-v-python#:%7E:text=%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%20numpy%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD,%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0.)

### Пример

**Код**

```
import numpy as np 

cubes = [125, -64, 27, -8, 1] 
cube_roots = np.cbrt(cubes) 
print(cube_roots)
```

**Вывод**

```
[ 5. -4.  3. -2.  1.]
```

Comment: На примере из вопроса numpy даёт точно такой же неточный результат 26.999999999999996

Comment: @andreymal, извиняюсь, безрассудную теорию предложил. Проверить сам не успеваю, т.к. на завтра праздничную программу готовлю XD

Comment: Даже если использовать максимально точный вещественный тип `np.float128`, всё-равно точно 27 в `numpy` никак не получится.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вы хотели просто решить проблему неточного извлечения корней из точных кубов, но получилось как получилось:

```
import struct
from fractions import Fraction


def difference(float_expected, float_root, degree):
    '''
    Возвращает разницу между степенью корня и ожидаемым значением
    '''

    fraction_expected = Fraction.from_float(float_expected)
    fraction_root = Fraction.from_float(float_root)
    return abs(fraction_expected - fraction_root ** degree)


def ternary_search(lower_bound, upper_bound, function):
    '''
    Находит целое значение x из промежутка [lower_bound, upper_bound),
    для которого значение function(x) минимально
    '''

    while lower_bound + 3 < upper_bound:
        mid1 = (lower_bound * 2 + upper_bound) // 3
        mid2 = (lower_bound + upper_bound * 2) // 3
        res1 = function(mid1)
        res2 = function(mid2)
        if res1 < res2:
            upper_bound = mid2
        else:
            lower_bound = mid1

    return min(range(lower_bound, upper_bound), key=function)


def create_float(exponent, mantissa):
    '''
    Создает число binary64 IEEE-754 по экспоненте и мантиссе
    '''
    
    number = (exponent << 52) + mantissa
    return struct.unpack('d', number.to_bytes(8, 'little'))[0]


def precise_root(float_value, degree):
    '''
    Возвращает максимально точное значение корня среди всех возможных
    значений binary64 IEEE-754 (используя только стандартный формат
    1-11-52, исключая все субнормальные и специальные значения)

    value - положительное число с плавающей запятой
    degree - положительное целое число больше единицы
    '''
    
    nearest_values = [float_value ** (1 / degree)]
    min_difference = difference(float_value, nearest_values[0], degree)
    for exponent in range(1023, 2047):
        calc_difference = lambda x: difference(float_value,
                                               create_float(exponent, x),
                                               degree)
        mantissa = ternary_search(0, 2 ** 52, calc_difference)
        diff = difference(float_value, create_float(exponent, mantissa), degree)
        if diff < min_difference:
            nearest_values = [create_float(exponent, mantissa)]
        elif diff == min_difference:
            nearest_values.append(create_float(exponent, mantissa))

    return nearest_values[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    value = 1000000001.0
    degree = 9
    root = precise_root(value, degree)
    diff = difference(value, root, degree)
    print(format(root, '.70f'))
    print(format(value ** (1 / degree), '.70f'))
    print(format(float(diff), '.70f'))
    print(format(float(difference(value, value ** (1 / degree), degree)), '.70f'))
    # 10.0000000011111112030448566656559705734252929687500000000000000000000000
    # 10.0000000011111094266880172654055058956146240234375000000000000000000000
    # 0.0000000831848155171970377866333596662828941958878203877247869968414307
    # 0.0000015155363413641129334422444352448167137481505051255226135253906250
```